# Taking a user input as a string and rearrange the order of words?

Tags: java, string

Ok. So I am trying to run a program and it is not working out so good. I think I'm close but missing a step.

I ask users to enter one phrase (completely random) and then I ask them to enter another phrase that is three words and all the words are together. And the goal of the program is to print out phrase one but to have the position of third word in the second phrase at position one. Also I want to have word one and three capatilized.

```
User input : My name is George
user input: name is George

desired output: my GEORGE is NAME
```

This is what I have.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assign3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String one, two, three,four, five,six,seven,eight;
        Scanner kbrd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter a phrase, and then pick three words that you want to switch");
        one= kbrd.nextLine();

        two= kbrd.next();
        three = kbrd.next();
        four = kbrd.next();
        seven = two+three+four;

        System.out.println(one.indexOf(two));
        System.out.println(one.lastIndexOf(four));

        five = four.toUpperCase()+three+two.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(five);

        eight = one.replace(seven,five);
        System.out.println(eight);
    }
}
```

Comment: your desired output doesn't match your description.

Comment: Ok, how should i of phrased it?

Comment: You have two phrases:  (My name is George) and (name is George).  "print out phrase one but have the position of word three in the second phrase at position one"  Doesn't that mean "George name is George"?

Comment: My intended thought was that you would read the two phrases as entirely seperate. So position one of the second phrase would be George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost got it what you were missing are a few spaces because of which it didn't find your string and replace it.

New code should look like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
String one, two, three,four, five,six,seven,eight;
      Scanner kbrd = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("please enter a phrase, and then pick three words that you want to switch");
      one= kbrd.nextLine();

      two= kbrd.next()+" "; // Added space
      three = kbrd.next()+" "; // Added space
      four = kbrd.next()+" "; // Added space
      seven = two+three+four;

      System.out.println(one.indexOf(two));
      System.out.println(one.lastIndexOf(four));

      five = four.toUpperCase()+three+two.toUpperCase();
      System.out.println(five);

      eight = one.replace(seven.trim(),five.trim()); // timing the last space
      System.out.println(eight);
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
please enter a phrase, and then pick three words that you want to switch
My name is George
name is George
3
-1
GEORGE is NAME 
My GEORGE is NAME
```

Comment: Runs great now. Thank you for your help. Although I love answers, I like explanations as well. Could you tell me how you figured the quotations would solve the problem, as well as the trim?

Comment: I did mention in the answer that because you were missing them it would not replace it. When i ran you code i got "GEORGEisNAME " in the five. So i knew that would be a problem. Debugging your code should be very helpful !

Comment: Ok, your right. Thanks. To take this problem a step further. If the user entered Name IS George. How do I make the program search for this phrase regardless of the capitalization?