# How to change the words in a string and reprint the original string but with the new arrangement of words?

Tags: java, string, search, uppercase

Code :

```
String one, two, three,four, five,six,seven,eight;
Scanner kbrd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter a phrase, and then pick three words that you want to switch");
one= kbrd.nextLine();
two= kbrd.next() +" ";
three = kbrd.next()+" ";
four = kbrd.next()+ " ";
two.toLowerCase();
three.toLowerCase();
four.toLowerCase();
seven = two+three+four;
System.out.println(one.indexOf(two));
System.out.println(one.lastIndexOf(four));
five = four.toUpperCase()+three+two.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(five);
eight = one.replace(seven.trim(),five.trim());
System.out.println(eight)
```

It works but when someone inputs the second user input with Name is George it won't re-arrange the words to say GEORGE IS NAME. It works if the two user inputs are My name is george. name is george. Any ideas how to fix this? My theory is that it can't find it in the orginal sentence and therfore it doesn't know what to replace because what it is replacing isn't in the original.

Comment: You could use collections.shuffle ! to shuffle the words !

Comment: That might work but I really want to figure this out using basic string commands. and I have no idea how to use shuffle lol.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I guess yesterday you had your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024152/taking-a-user-input-as-a-string-and-rearrange-the-order-of-words) solved. Please be more clear on what your actual problem is since it's a bit confusing (at least for me).

Comment: Could you give some sample input and the desired output? I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. Is it just take 3 words from a phrase and reverse their order? (e.g. "1 2 3 4 5" > "1 4 3 2 5")

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use [Collections.Shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Your new code would look like :

```
eight = one.replace(seven.trim(),five.trim());
// System.out.println(eight)
List<String> sentence = Arrays.asList(eight.trim().split(" "));
Collections.shuffle(sentence);
for(String str : sentence) {
   System.out.println(str+" ");
}
```